# how to reverse the firebase realtime database or display data in descending order when fetching from firebase database in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how to reverse this or how to display data in descending order when we using firebaseanimationlist i see lots content but i cannot find the solution please help me on this topic when we use firebaseanimationlist or fetch data from firebasedatabase it comes in accending order please provide answer on this topic

```
import 'package:college_notification_app/notificationScreen/singleDataScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'displayData.dart';

class AllNotificationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllNotificationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String routeName = '/allNotificationScreen';

  @override
  State<AllNotificationScreen> createState() => _AllNotificationScreenState();
}

class _AllNotificationScreenState extends State<AllNotificationScreen> {
  final query = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Post');
  final fileRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/file');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7877BB),
        systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Color(0xFF7877BB),
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        title: const Text(
          'All Notification',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),

      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: FirebaseAnimatedList(

                query: query,
                itemBuilder: (context, snapshot, animation, index) {
                  String id = snapshot.child('id').value.toString();
                  String subject = snapshot.child('subject').value.toString();
                  String message = snapshot.child('message').value.toString();
                  String fileUrl = snapshot.child('fileUrl0').value.toString();
                  String dateTime = snapshot.child('dateTime').value.toString();

                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      print(id);
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SingleDataScreen(childId: id)),
                      );
                    },
                    child: ContentCard(
                        subject: subject, message: message, fileUrl: fileUrl),
                  );
                },
              )),
          Container(color: Colors.transparent)
          //start
          //end
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```